# Pushing values to localstorage in angularjs not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage, angular-local-storage

I am getting value from firebase when i push the value to localstorage empty srting is push how to fix it

my code :

```
    var app = angular.module("bucksbucketapplication", ['firebase', 'ngStorage']);
app.controller("bucksbucket_orders", function ($scope, $firebaseArray, $firebaseObject, $http, $localStorage) {
    var fbvalues = new Firebase("https://qwertyuiop.firebaseio.com/values");
    $scope.syncfromfbvalues = $firebaseArray(fbvalues);
    $scope.$storage = $localStorage.$default({
        "orders": []
    });
    $scope.data = $localStorage.orders;
    $scope.cloneItem = function (syncfromfbvalues) {
        $scope.$storage.orders.push({
            "price": syncfromfbvalues.id
        });
    }
});
```

and front my end code :

```
<html ng-app="bucksbucketapplication">

<head>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="angularfire.min.js"></script>
    <script src="ngstr.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="bucksbucket_orders">

         <li ng-repeat="message in syncfromfbvalues">{{message.greens}} <button class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="cloneItem(syncfromfbvalues)">to local</button></li>
</body>

</html>
```

and [My Plunker Demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/r1POZf/preview)

Comment: What is this `todo` variable you are passing into `data-ng-click`? also `$scope` in `cloneItem` is looking at the `$scope` of your controller, not the `ng-repeat` one, so `$scope.message` is undefined.

Comment: @Rhumborl hi i update the code can you please look the updated code and plunker too and could you explain in plunker why i"m not getting the value ?

Answer (score 1):

Hi problem got fixed and this is the [Updated Plunker Demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/r1POZf/preview)

reason as Rhumborl told in comment i worng send variable and now i got fixed

updated code

`data-ng-click="cloneItem(message)"` and then in script

```
$scope.cloneItem = function (message) {
        $scope.$storage.orders.push({
          "price": message.greens
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Intstead of creating reference to $localStorage directly save values to the $localStorage.

```
$localStorage.orders = []
$scope.cloneItem = function (todo) {
    $localStorage.orders.push({
        "price": $scope.message
    });
}
```

I faced the same issue when I was working on it and it worked for me this way.

Comment: Sorry , it"s not working .. value not sending  to local .. did you try the plunker demo ?

Comment: hi ng-localstorage working fine but i can"t get the value from  `"price": $scope.message.greens` if i put   `"price": $scope.message` i can get the value as it"s of js script i"m pushing into it
"

Answer (score 0):

Use promise for asynchronous call. I made some changes into your example. Your messages object is undefined because of asynchronous operation. I added promise, so it's handled now.

**Working example:**
http://plnkr.co/edit/I1Dyn0NmuLMDRYyS8ABU?p=preview

```
                $scope.getMessages = function () {
                var arr, fbvalues = new Firebase("https://qwertyuiop.firebaseio.com/values");
                arr = $firebaseArray(fbvalues);
                arr.$loaded().then(function (msg) {
                    console.log('Mymsg', msg)
                    return $scope.message = msg;
                });
            };
```